# UIscrollView with image rotation

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I want to make application like image album.
like the user scroll horizontally and set the new image at center. image size is only 130*130 size and images are received through web service. at a time there are  3 images seen on screen. when user scroll next image set the next image as a middle image......

when user scroll horizontally the UIlabel exactly at the bottom display the name of image which is store in array.

i want make it look like iphone coverflow type application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but if as you say you want to make it *'look like an iphone coverflow type application'*  why not consider one of the several open source components that exist already? Here are two good options:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/mac-os-x/controls/mbcoverflowview

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-coverflow

Comment: thanx for your reply. my exactly question is that, i want to put labels at the bottom part when we scroll the images either using coverflow or similar method.